# What is the LaTeX code to put a multiplication symbol into a matplotlib title?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, matplotlib

Apologies for a very basic question, but this is something that I always forget, and it's a pain to find with google and the like, so I'm putting it here for everyone's future reference.

As far as I recall, it's `$\times$` but that's not working in a `matplotlib` plot title (perhaps because `matplotlib` doesn't implement that particular symbol?).

I get something like "A `imes` B" (with `imes` in latex font) for the title "A $\times$ B".

Comment: `\times` or `\cdot` comes with any basic installation. Please, add an example.

Comment: I was mostly intending to put it here as a reference, so it could be found more easily. But the problem I have has been solved by @Henri's answer.. so perhaps I'll rephrase the question and google will find it for those seeking 'multiplication symbol'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This example works as expected: (note the `r` in front of the title string)

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title(r'$A \times B$')
plt.plot([0,1,2])
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

> [image]

Comment: yep, it was the missing `r`

Comment: Is it just an artifact of the resolution of the screenshot, or is the `\times`-`B` spacing really that much tighter that the `A`-`\times` spacing in the output?

Comment: Interesting. I get the same effect. There's a technical name for calculating inter-character spacing when italics and the like are at play. Such typsetting effects are indeed a dark art!